# communication between 3 raspberry pi

Tags: python, sockets

**I am trying to send data from 2 raspberry pi's ( model 2B) to a single raspberry pi through the ethernet port. I do the communication between 2 pi's via ethernet port. The code corresponding to that would be provided below.**

**Transmitter Side:**

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.53"
UDP_Port = 1452
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_Port
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_Port))

**Receiver Side:**
import socket

UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_Port =1452
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # Internet UDP              
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_Port))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

**How can receive data from 2 pis to a single raspberry pi through the ethernet port? Is it possible to do this?**

Comment: yes of course its possible! anything is possible. What you need to do is the have the receiver raspberry as a server and the other two as clients.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your help.. I did it as u suggested.